# How to create a globally available WebClient object

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

I have a download program in windows forms which downloads the html source code of a bunch of URLs and extract further URLs and downloads that stuff too. I am using

```
using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    // Do download stuff here...
}
```

but .NET Mem profiler shows a severe memory leak because a lot of object are garbage collected but not disposed OR disposed but not garbage collected. Sound weird to me but my program has a memory leak.

To get a feel of my program consider this code please:

```
private void PreprocessURLs(List<string> URLs)
{
    using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
       // Download first batch of html source code and put in a List<string> property
    }
}

private void ProcessURLs(List<string> URLs)
{
    using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
       // Download more stuff and save them
    }
}
```

and so on. This is not the actual program but what I want to show you is, how do I create a "globally" available WebClient object/instance so I do not create a bunch off client objects? I want to reuse it. I suspect this to be the cause (maybe among others) to cause the memory leak. Maybe I am wrong because I have never created a program with a task where it could have a memory leak.

EDIT: After suggestion of tlemster I created a static instance of WebClient but that causes an I/O error because concurrent I/O are not supported (DownloadFileAsync()).

EDIT1: Here is my download method which does the main work and blocking my UI thread by doing so. Thus I believe the mem leak comes from this function.

```
private void Download()
{
    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    string bla;
    string chapterName;
    string bla1;
    string chapterNumber;
    List<Tuple<string, int>> temp = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();

    // Contains all URLs from preprocessing
    foreach (var chapter in Chapters)
    {
        bla = chapter.Item2;
        chapterName = ReplaceSpecialChars(bla);

        bla1 = chapter.Item3;
        chapterNumber = ReplaceSpecialChars(bla1);

        // Skip this chapter if it already exists based on chapter name
        if (Directory.Exists(string.Format("{0}/{1} - {2}", chapter.Item4, chapterNumber, chapterName)))
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(string.Format("{0}/{1} - {2}", chapter.Item4, chapterNumber, chapterName));
        }

        // Process each chapter and extract other URLs
        foreach (var item in GetPagesLink(chapter.Item1))
        {
            // Add the extracted URLs to a list for download further down
            temp.Add(new Tuple<string, int>(GetImageLink(item.Item1), item.Item2));
        }

        stopwatch.Start();

        // The download of the files I want after processing it two times
        foreach (var img in temp)
        {
            // A static WebClient does not work because DownloadFileAsync() does not support concurrent I/O
            // Atm should not matter because this whole thing is not async anyway...
            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
                webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(img.Item1), string.Format("{0}/{1} - {2}/{3}.jpg", chapter.Item4, chapterNumber, chapterName, img.Item2)); // TODO: Find image type and replace hardcoded jpg
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(150);
            }
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();
        temp.Clear();
        txtDebug.AppendText("Finished chapter " + chapter.Item3 + " : " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "\r\n");
        stopwatch.Reset();
    }
    Chapters.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Are you certain that the leaky memory comes from `WebClient` objects - at that they're always in `using` blocks?

Comment: I dont see any other possibility but alas this is my first time dealing with memory issues and I am still learning c#. I will update my post to only show the download method which is running constantly (and blocking my program, but that is another issue). As it is the only thing running it should be caused by this method somehow (the mem leak).

Comment: Your use of `WebClient` is the one part of your code which _cannot_ have a memory leak (nor a resource leak). Since it's created and used in a `using` block, it's safe.

Comment: The remainder of the program is blocked by this download method. And if there is no memory leak from it what could cause it if nothing else "runs"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Store the created WebClient in a static field, which keeps the instance alive as long as your program is running or until you get rid of it manually.

Comment: I think his answer is valid. It is just that Webclient doesn't support input/output for download file async but for every other Webclient usage I made it static. In this case it is kind of global, I guess